# Почему не выводится alert?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот код

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js">
    $(function () {
        alert('Ok');
    });
</script>
```

При загрузке документа должно бы по идее выводиться OK. Но не выводится. Почему?

Comment: Пусть меня поправят, если я буду нести ерись, но Вы разве не безымянную функцию объявляее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот так:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        alert('Ok');
    });
</script>
```

всё работает